# In the image, what does Hadley mean by simplifying when applying matrix subsetting?

Tags: r

[image]

[http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcZ50.png)

I do not understand the meaning of 'simplification' in the above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the screenshot really, and by running the code you'd see it in practice.

Basically, if you select a single column and simplify, the output is a vector.

Without simplification, it's a data frame of one column.

Answer (score 0):

Look at output of `?drop`. When you subset either dataframes, matrices or arrays and get a result that has a "lower dimension", then the dimension of the result will be lowered to become "simpler".

```
dim( matrix(1:4, 2)[ , 1])
NULL  # a single row or single column result will become an atomic vector
```

If you set drop=FALSE as an argument, then you can prevent this effect.

```
dim( matrix(1:4, 2)[ , 1, drop=FALSE])  # also works for dataframes
[1] 2 1
```